# Why Muhammad is considered as messanger of God and peace

Tags: history, prophet-muhammad

I am a Hindu who knows very little about Islam. Recently I read an article on Wikipedia about [Conversion of non-Muslim places of worship into mosques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_non-Muslim_places_of_worship_into_mosques).

If Mohammad converted many religious places related to Jewish or Christian people and killed many people than why is he considered as Messenger of God and peace?

Answer (score 8):

The article speaks about some different places, so I answer separately:

**Ka'aba:**

As it is pointed to in the article, according to both Islam and history, Ka'aba was built by Ibrahim, who was a monotheist and a prophet of God. He built Ka'aba as a place for worship of Allah. But years after Ibrahim died, it was converted to a place for idols and idolatry. When Mohammad brought Islam and only after the whole people of Mecca (truly or apparently) became Muslims, he broke all the idols in the Ka'aba.

**Other temples**:
As the article itself says, not even a non-Muslim temple converted to an Islamic place *in the lifetime of Mohammad*. But after him, and by other people it has happened, mostly after wars that Muslims were victorious and by soldiers and normal people. If somebody does something wrong and he names him/herself a Muslim, doesn't imply that Islam agrees with him/her. These days you can see lots of churches (and other temples) in Muslim countries even where more than 90 percent of people are Muslims.

Islam never forces people to do even minor things, as it said in the Quran:

> **لا اکراه فی الدین**
>
> **There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion.**

Destruction of religious temples surely is not accepted by Islam, and never has happened in the lifetime of Mohammad.

But please note that in some cases referred to in the Wikipedia article, people of that city/area themselves became Muslims and then converted the temples to mosques.

I hope that all of us think carefully about everything that we see/hear/read before we accept them as facts.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I can only give you +1 but you deserve +10.